# Eager loading of variant images

Tags: eager-loading, variants

In a commerce store that I'm trying out, my product variants have a variant image field.

I need to get an array of all the variant images in my product template.

I know I can do something like

`{% set variantImages = product.variants|map(variant => variant.variantImage.one() )}`

but I believe this will execute a query for each variant.

I am aware of [eager loading in craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html), but I am not sure how to use it in this case, as I am not writing a query to get the product or variants - craft auto-injects those into the product template.

How would I eager load the assets of a variant from within the product template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eager-load elements that were already loaded (like an Entry or Product that Craft set up for you "outside" a template) like this:

```
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(
  className(product),
  [product],
  [
    ['variants.variantImage', { withTransforms: ['thumbnail'] }],
  ]
) %}
```

This will load + set any downstream elements, just as though you'd chained an equivalent `.with()` on the original query.

A couple notes:

- `className()` is used to capture the fully-qualified name of the Element class. It's required to let Craft know what kind of eager-loadable properties the specific Element Type has;
- `[product]` is an array, because eager-loading is always done in "bulk," even for a single source element;

You can do a similar thing directly on the Variants, if you've got a reference to them, already:

```
{% set variants = product.variants %}
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(
  className(variants | first),
  variants,
  [
    ['variantImage', { withTransforms: ['thumbnail'] }],
  ]
) %}
```